# executing exe files in electron html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I'm want to create a simple electron desctop app that executes a file when pressing a button in the html part. somehow i get several errors. First I got this require is not defined error, when fixing it by enabling node integration in main js I got:

```
"util.js:176 Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at Object.jQueryDetection (util.js:176)
    at util.js:192
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6"
```

node jquery and bootstrap are supposed to be properly embedded.

**This is my main.js:**

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

function chrome(){
       execFile("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", function(err, data) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
    };

var btn = document.getElementById("#TestBtn");
btn.addEventListener('click', chrome);
```

**my html.logic.js:** :

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');


const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', function(){
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true,

  }));
});
```

```
**and my mainwindow.html:**
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Youtube Downloader</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Youtube Downloader</h1>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Download!</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Put your link in here!" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
  </div>
  <div class="DowLs">
    <ul class="list-group"><h1>Downloads:</h1>
      <li class="list-group-item">Video Name<br><br>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%"></div>
        </div></li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Video Name<br><br>
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%"></div>
          </div></li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Video Name<br><br>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
            </div></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Video Name<br><br>
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div>
              </div></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="TestBtn">Dark</button>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="html_logic.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an interesting write up on this: https://techsparx.com/nodejs/electron/load-jquery-bootstrap.html

Essentially:

> The effect is that if jQuery is executing in a Node.js/CommonJS environment it does not create a global jQuery object. While Electron is a Chrome browser, it also has Node.js support including the module and module.exports objects, and the require function, and so forth. Therefore when executed under Electron, jQuery runs the first branch and does not add itself to the global object, and instead exports itself via module.exports.

So you need to do:

```html
<script>
    window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
</script>
```

This is because of the way jQuery loads, it ends up exporting it instead of adding it to the window global scope.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've been searching for a solution all day long :D but im left with a different error message now : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at html_logic.js:11

Comment: Post a new question :D

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be that much of an issue to answer it right here. But still, thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: It technically wouldn't be too much of an issue, except it's good practice on SO to separate questions so that they may help future users. If this answer solved your first question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: i figured out myself. i had to remove the # at the get element by id

Comment: I had to install jquery locally to get it working,                    npm install jquery